# Sufficient API Response for Mobile App

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm creating an API for my mobile app with Laravel - Lumen and i have the following scenario which i don't know what is the most sufficient way to return the response to my Android / IOS App,

lets assume that the user is trying to sign in (same end point):

Case 1 :  the user provide the correct data for the sign in.

Case 2 :  the user sign in with wrong password.

Case 3 :  the user is not exist and have to sign up first.

My question is what should my API response look like in order i can differentiate those cases in my App logic and to move forward accordingly (I need to know which case is occurred ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response would be below -

```
Use this response if request validated successfully. 
{"status":"OK", "message":"success"}

Use this response if user not exist.
{"status":"FAIL", "message":"not_register"}

Use this response for invalid credentials.
{"status":"FAIL", "message":"invalid_credentials"}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I will track the Status as integer values (Status_Code)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the status into the response, it's efficient to return appropriate HTTP status codes:

For example:

1. Http Status: 200 - OK
2. Http Status: 404 - Not found
3. Http Status: 401 - Unauthorised

This way, your application can easily identify and catch HTTP errors in other parts of your application too.